# Missing space in bounty notice on a post

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

I noticed there is a space missing in the bounty message on a post:

[image: bounty message showing missing space]

<s>Link to example post: [Do you pay a gold tax when beating the final boss?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/401887/do-you-pay-a-gold-tax-when-beating-the-final-boss)</s> The bounty has since ended on the example post, [but any of the posts on StackOverflow that have a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=bounties) can also be referred to).

Comment: Same bug as the one affecting the migration notice, which [I posted on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423569). That one has been marked as [[meta-tag:status-review]] to escalate it to staff's attention. It should be on their radar now.

Comment: [Also happening with suggested edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423591/208273).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue! It is fixed now.