# Missing space in suggested edit notification

Tags: bug, user-interface

I suggested an edit on *[Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)*, and it said:

> Thanks for submitting an edit.It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members.

It should say:

> Thanks for submitting an edit. It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members.

Comment: Same bug as in the [bounty notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387395/323179).

Comment: And also [migration banner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423569/2821954).