# 'Thanks for submitting an edit' banner is missing a space

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, post-notices, whitespace

After you submit an edit, the following banner is shown:

> **Thanks for submitting an edit.**It is only visible to you until it’s been approved by trusted community members.

It seems that there is a space missing between both sentences.

[image: screenshot of banner with hand-drawn arrow pointing towards the missing space]

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [Missing space after submitting suggested edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423591/4946380) – and also affecting bounties: [Missing space in bounty notice on a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387395/294691)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this issue! It is fixed now.