# Missing space in migration banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, whitespace

> This question was [migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) from Super User because it can be answered on Meta Stack Exchange.[Migrated](https://superuser.com/posts/1775751/revisions) 4 days ago.

I've noticed this in a couple of migrated questions recently - someone adjusted the code for migration banners and forgot a space between "Exchange." and the second link "Migrated"?

Comment: Likely the same issue as ['Thanks for submitting an edit' banner is missing a space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387529/thanks-for-submitting-an-edit-banner-is-missing-a-space) and [Missing space in bounty notice on a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387395/missing-space-in-bounty-notice-on-a-post). Good to know it also happens for bounties, although I'm guessing it was caused by the same issue as those two

Comment: @Randal'Thor FYI, this has already been reported about 3 weeks ago on Meta StackOverlow at [The case of the missing space](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423569/11726740), with it being set to "Status-Review" shortly afterwards. Regarding this issues of a missing space also occurring in bounty notices, in addition to the one here of [Missing space in bounty notice on a post](/q/387395) mentioned in cocomac's comment, it's also been reported on Meta Mathematics at [bad break in bounty banner](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35562).

Comment: There is a global bug in all post notices, for a long time, with the missing space. I don't think it's good idea to report it for each type of post notice on its own.

Comment: @Shadow I'm pretty sure it's a relatively recent bug, in migration banners at least? What do you mean by "a long time"?

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard the HTML encoding bug wasn't solved on one go. Essentially each instance of encoded text had to be reported in the end. We still don't know if all instances of it were fixed or there are more unreported ones. I have no faith at all for what seems to be a simple bug to be fixed in one go. I see no harm in reporting each. If each has to be solved, then this helps keeping track of them. If it's a single fix then staff have to slap on a few [status-completed] and done. Seems like no huge harm done, no huge time lost.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard Unless the bugtracking is *so cumbersome* that we shouldn't be doing it? In which case, that's probably what should be addressed by staff. Not trying to prevent reports. Also none of our concern, either. As users, reporting bugs should be fine. If staff want to limit this, then they have the power to announce a policy change for how bugs are to be reported. Until then, I feel like your ideas for what is good to report or not are a bit overstepping.

Comment: Per the MSO post linked above, this bug has been fixed (as have the bugs reported in the MSE issues linked above).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Thanks for submitting an edit' banner is missing a space](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387529/thanks-for-submitting-an-edit-banner-is-missing-a-space)

Comment: Moving to leave open per @VLAZ-onstrike-'s comments above.